# Passing credentials variables to powershell script in Jenkins

Tags: powershell, matlab, jenkins

I am trying to run MATLAB script inside powershell in one of the stages like this

```
withCredentials([[$class: 'UsernamePasswordMultiBinding', credentialsId: "${myID}", usernameVariable: 'USERNAME', passwordVariable: 'PASSWORD']])
{
script {
            env.VAL_RESULT = powershell(script: "matlab -wait -r \"JUsername='$USERNAME';JPassword='$PASSWORD';modelValidation;\"", returnStatus: true)
            if(env.VAL_RESULT == "1" ) {
                unstable("Failed")
            }
        }
}
```

Trying to do this will give a warning in console like

*Warning: A secret was passed to "powershell" using Groovy String interpolation, which is insecure.
Affected argument(s) used the following variable(s): [PASSWORD, USERNAME]
See https://jenkins.io/redirect/groovy-string-interpolation for details.*

In-order to solve the warning, I had to encapsulate powershell scripts within single quotes like

```
withCredentials([[$class: 'UsernamePasswordMultiBinding', credentialsId: '${myID}', usernameVariable: 'USERNAME', passwordVariable: 'PASSWORD']])
{
script {
            env.VAL_RESULT = powershell(script: 'matlab -wait -r \"JUsername='$USERNAME';JPassword='$PASSWORD';modelValidation;\"', returnStatus: true)
            if(env.VAL_RESULT == "1" ) {
                unstable("Failed")
            }
        }
}
```

Now the script doesn't exit. I believe that there is something wrong with the way I have used single quotes in JPassword='$PASSWORD'. Can anyone tell me if there is a way to escape single quote?

Comment: Try: `script: 'matlab -wait -r "JUsername=\'$env:USERNAME\';JPassword=\'$env:PASSWORD\';modelValidation;'`